# ImageMagick chop to remove whitespace rows in image

Tags: image, imagemagick, crop, imagemagick-convert, gimp

Trying to remove white space rows in an image:

[image]

I tried :

```
convert image_name.png -chop 110x170 + 240x300 chopped.png
```

as pixels 110-170 and 240-300 need to be cut. 
The resulting image should retain all sub images with little white space.
I am very open to suggestions, also beyond imagemagic, as long as it can be done in the terminal and to multiple image batches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
convert kernel.png -chop x60+0+240 -chop x60+0+110 result.png
```

[image]

The syntax is:

```
-chop WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFFSET+YOFFSET
```

as I didn't specify the width, it chops the whole lot. I worked out the height by subtracting 110 from 170 to give 60. The x-offset is zero because I am cutting the entire width and the y-offset is 110 because that's the distance from the top.

Note that I did 2 separate chops, one for each chunk of white-space to be removed.

Note that I did the lower chop first because the image is *"shuffled up"* to fill the gaps, so if you start at the bottom, each chop only shuffles stuff that will be unaffected by subsequent chops.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How to horizontally/vertically chop from say for example +245+15 to +50+125?

Comment: @AhmadIsmail You probably want `-crop 195x110+50+15` but ask a new question with diagram if not.

Comment: Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75853480/1772898) with more details.