# How to chop (remove area from side and middle of) an image?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to chop an image. I can graphically do it by: `display sample.png` and then *Transform > Chop > Direction > vertical* and then drag a line.

[image: Screenshot]

However, I need to do it via CLI.

I found some hint from [ImageMagick chop to remove whitespace rows in image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57146002/1772898).

I also found an [example](https://superuser.com/a/1161341) to use `-chop` with `-gravity`. For example,

```
convert sample.png -gravity South -chop 0x20 result.png
```

But what I am looking for is something like:

```
convert sample.png -chop-point-a +245+15 -chop-point-b +50+125 -direction vertical result.png
```

How can I do that?

To be more specific I want the following as input:

[image: Input]

and the following as output:

[image: Output]

You can see that a table was separated in two pages and I merged them as one table.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you want to do. Can you show the image you start with (probably marked up in some way) and the image you want to get as a result please?

Comment: I added the input and the output image. I modified the image using the graphical method described in the question. I am looking for the cli method.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it! Where is `pointA`? And `pointB`? Can you mark them on the image please? And how can  `+245+15` and `+50+125 ` possibly crop anything from the middle of a 1200x3300pixel image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still fail to understand your question - either where the unmarked points are that you are referring to, or how the offsets you have given could possibly relate to an image with your dimensions.

Here is how I would extract the parts you seem to require:

```
magick WfAqm.png -write MPR:orig -crop 606x1008+332+343 \( MPR:orig -crop 606x1039+332+1982 \) -append result.png
```

[image]

That loads your image, and makes copy in a *"Magick Persistent Register"* called `orig`. I do that so I can refer to it later for cropping a second time without having to read from disk again. Then I crop the first table of text with `-crop 606x1008+332+343`. Then, in some *"aside-processing"* I get the copy of your original image back from the MPR and crop that with `606x1039+332+1982`. Then I append the two resulting tables one-above-the-other.

Comment: I used `convert` instead of `magick` and it worked like a charm. I have a question though. Where did you get `606x1039+332+1982` and `606x1008+332+343`?

Comment: I measured them off the image... 606x1039+332+1982 means 606px wide and 1039px tall starting at (332,1982) from the top-left corner.